# Can't write int to file using fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite

I'm trying to format my keylog output so it shows time:

```
        t = time(0);
        now = localtime(&t);


        if(now->tm_min != prevM && now->tm_hour != prevH)
        {
            prevM = now->tm_min;
            prevH = now->tm_hour;

            fwrite("[", 1, sizeof(WCHAR), keylog);
            fwrite(&prevH, 1, sizeof(int), keylog);
            fwrite("]", 1, sizeof(WCHAR), keylog);
            fwrite(" ", 1, sizeof(WCHAR), keylog);
            fflush(keylog);
        }
```

but instead of readable number I get "[ DLE NUL ] " written in my file, where DLENUL is question mark.

How do I make it to write a readable number?

Comment: Look up [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/).

Answer (score 5):

Use `fprintf` as others are also suggesting.

Reason:
`fwrite` is generally used to write in binary files to write blocks of same type of data.

The data you are writing looks like a character string, you can use `fprintf` with following syntax to write your complete data in the file.

```
 fprintf(keylog, "[%d] ", prevH);
```

It seems you are writing wide characters (as you use `wchar`). You can use different format specifiers accordingly.

Comment: `fprintf(keylog, "[%d:%d] ", prevH, prevM);` solved the problem, but now when I'm writing to file what I got from keyboard
`fwrite(&outputChar, 1, sizeof(WCHAR), keylog);`
in my out put I get character together with NULL sign, because it is WCHAR

Comment: Is there a way to fix this? I tried with different specifiers, but my output is always like "[17:13] tNULLeNULLsNULLtNULL".
If I write chars instead of wchars, everything is ok, but I need wchars.

Comment: Do you *really* need wchars *in the file*? If so, use `fwprintf` and friends (and you have to open the file differently, too).  But I suspect you should actually *not* be using wchars *at all*.  The ISO C wide/multibyte character feature was designed at a time when we hadn't figured out how to do i18n properly, and it shows; you're almost always better off using UTF-8 in narrow strings, either by hand or with a third-party library (such as [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/)) whose design is equal to the true complexity of the job.

Answer (score 3):

With `fwrite` you are storing the binary representation. If you want to store a textual representation you can use `fprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
fwrite(&prevH, 1, sizeof(int), keylog);
```

try

```
fprintf(keylog, "%d", prevH);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already suggested, you could use fprintf when writing text to a file.

More specifically, when writing WCHARs you can use either:

```
fwprintf(file, L"%c\n",outputChar);
```

or:

```
fprintf(file, "%lc", outputChar);
```

For more information, have a look at the documentation of the function:
[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/fwprintf/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/fwprintf/?kw=fwprintf)